# Remove background color and width from a dropdown nav element

Tags: css, wordpress, wpml

I am translating my site using the WPML plugin. As you can see by clicking the link below, if you hover over the flag, the nav dropdown inherits the classes of the rest of the nav (a white backround, padded width, etc). I would like to make the background transparent, so that only the flags appear. I have tried to target this several ways, but to no avail. Here is the CSS I am trying to use. Can anyone help?

```
.sub-menu is--forced-placed {
  width: auto;
  background-color: none;
  color: none;
}
```

Link to my site: http://www.wgeil.de

Comment: Just a simple query but is the image transparent background as well?

Comment: I see a minor syntax error here. `is--forced-placed` is not a valid css syntax. what's happening there is that it is trying to find elements `is--forced-placed` withing the dom of class `sub-menu`

Answer (score 0):

you can try the below css

```
ul.primary-menu>.menu-item.menu-item-has-children>.sub-menu{
background-color:transparent;
}
```

Comment: This is the closest anyone has come. But unfortunately it makes ALL of the dropdowns transparent (See my page). Is there some way to make only the language dropdown transparent? In addition, as you can see, the flag is not appearing directly below the other one. Is there some way to fix this?

Comment: what is `is--forced-placed` class for dropdown in your ul tag? its your custom class OR dynamically generated class?

Comment: It is dynamically generated. Perhaps by WPML?

Answer (score 0):

ok, another try:

your css selector should look like
`.sub-menu.is--forced-placed` because both classes are on the ul element. but if you use this selector it wont work because there is another css rule that overwrite this. we have to add the ul to the selector: `ul.sub-menu.is--forced-placed`. now this selector will overwrite the other rules appended to this element.

another thing is the `min-width` rule on your dropdowns affects the language dropdown to stretch to `min-width: 13.75rem;`. so we have to overwrite this too.

the last thing to say is that you cant set `background-color` or `color` to `none`. you have to use `transparent`.

try this css and tell us if this will work:

```
ul.sub-menu.is--forced-placed {
    min-width: auto;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: a bit of explanation of what's happening would help the OP

Answer (score 0):

Looking through the inspect, if you can find a way to add `background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);` to the css below. You'll also want to remove the border So you don't get any funny lines.

```
ul.primary-menu > .menu-item.menu-item-has-children > .sub-menu {
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.075);
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%);  
}
```

Then it'll become transparent. Probably... Maybe..

The width I'm still looking at, but I'm also eating soup so I'm a tad slow right now.

Comment: the width comes from .primary-menu>ul .children, ul.primary-menu .sub-menu {     min-width: 13.75rem;
}

Answer (score 0):

This

```
ul.primary-menu>.menu-item.menu-item-has-children>.sub-menu{
background-color:transparent !important;
}
```

The `!important` makes it override all rules

```
.sub-menu is--forced-placed {
  width: auto !important;
  background-color: none !important;
  color: none !important;
}
```

But I would use the first example `background-color:transparent !important;` insted of `background-color:none !important;`